# access user data inside the iframe application facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i get the user details from the iframe application ?

the problem  is when i try to authenticate the user it authenticating and redirecting to the `SITE` not to facebook .

actually i am using signed_request to check user liked or not ,if liked i need to get the user details using the graph api [any other ways /javascript ?] so that i can save that on to database.

This is my current code

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']))
        {
            $encoded_sig = null;
            $payload = null;
            list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
            $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
            $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
            if($data->page->liked)
            {
                //liked


                $questions = $this->functions->get_questions();

                if($questions["status"] ==TRUE)
                {
                    $questions["data"] = $questions["data"]->result_array();
                    $this->load->view("public/contest",$questions);


                }
                else
                {
                    echo "FALSE";
                }



            }
            else {

                //not liked

                $this->load->view("public/continue");



            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). It allows you to get user id, and then query Graph API for some basic information. You can get more information about SDK and how to work with it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)